# Windows 10 can not search anything from start menu after I renamed my users folder

Tags: windows-10, users, user-folders

I installed windows few days ago and set user name as `[FirstName] [Last Name]`, some commands had problems to execute from CMD because my username had space in the middle. I logged in using administrator and renamed the folder to `[My Nickname]`, after that I'm geetting error that setup can't find directory `C:\Users\[First Name] [Last Name]\...` and when I try to search from start menu, it's not able to find anything

any ideas?

Comment: I would name the profile back to it's original name, then use the built-in functionality within Windows to change the profile name, that can be accomplished by attaching and disconnecting a Microsoft Account to the profile.

Comment: Registry hacks are bad practice, not needed for this, and may not last the life of the OS. Don’t use registry hacks for this

Comment: @John so what do you recommend? I don't see your answer

Comment: @John why??? Registry is the ultimate database where all the configuration settings of windows is stored and everything you do makes changes there. PS I didn't down vote you

Comment: Windows provides a way to do this (fix profiles) without using the Registry. This is always a preferable approach in my experience.

Comment: Author.  You cannot see my answer was downvoted and deleted. Sorry.

Comment: @Arkadi - John decided to delete their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must also do some registry changes to make windows recognize the new userprofile.

- Go to the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.
- Open cmd and run command `whoami /user` and note your SID.
- Now in the subkey that is your SID, there is a key named `ProfileImagePath` change it to new userprofile path. Then restart.